# exception handling in wdk

Tags: c++

I can't use exception handling in native subsystem.

This is my cpp file:

```
#include <ntddk.h>
#include <exception>

int __cdecl  main () {
    try
    {
      throw 20;

    }
    catch (int e)
    {

    }

    return 0;
}
```

And my sources file:

```
TARGETNAME = native
TARGETTYPE = PROGRAM
UMTYPE = nt
USER_C_FLAGS=$(USER_C_FLAGS) /EHa
SOURCES = exeption.cpp \

INCLUDES=$(DDK_INC_PATH)
MINWIN_SDK_LIB_PATH=$(SDK_LIB_PATH)
TARGETLIBS=$(NTDLL_CRT) $(SDK_LIB_PATH)\ntdll.lib lib.lib
```

And my error's are:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___CxxFrameHandler3 referenced in function __ehhandler$_main

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __EH_epilog3 referenced in function __catch$_main$0

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __EH_prolog3_catch referenced in function _main

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __CxxThrowException@8 referenced in function _main

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "const type_info::`vftable'" (??_7type_info@@6B@)
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Exception handling isn't a good idea in driver code anyway...  The vast majority of DDK drivers are written in C not C++...

Comment: [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487420) may help you in general. Specifically, it says "C++ exceptions require a kernel-mode-safe library, which does not currently exist." That was 2007; don't know but I doubt things have changed since then.

Comment: re your comment "What are the exact drawbacks of using exceptions in drivers? and why is it dangerous?" exceptions result in some truly horrendous codegen and don't really solve any problems we can't solve better with good code. they suck performance and introduce yet another point of failure where you must rely on the library... most places i have worked they are forbidden by the coding standard. i only grudgingly turn them on now because ms have forced the issue with windows rt. rtti is another thing where the implementation is horrible, in both cases they make you pay for what you don't use

Answer (score 0):

This problem is described here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22801/Drivers-Exceptions-and-C with solution that probably works, but may cause undefined behavior.

However, your problem is more simple: you need to write user-mode program with some DDK stuff. Just use VC++ build environment (or Windows SDK) which includes all CRT libraries by default, and include ntddk.h file for DDK stuff.

If you want to use C++ exceptions in drivers, the answer is simple: never do this.

Comment: thanks for answering i'm not writing a driver i'm building code in native subsystem

Comment: What are the exact drawbacks of using exceptions in drivers? and why is it dangerous?

Comment: 1. Home-made solution like in the CodeProject article may work, but actually can cause undefined behavior once per month on some client sites - the worst scenario in program development.

Comment: 2. KMDF framework supports only C language, so we can forget about C++ writing KMDF drivers.